# ¿Como eliminar una palabra clave de un texto en C?

Tags: c, array, string, punteros

**Tengo un ejericio que dice:**

Codificar un programa que lea por teclado una palabra clave de hasta 15 caracteres y un texto de
hasta n líneas (siendo n un valor constante). El programa deberá eliminar del texto aquellas
líneas que contengan la palabra clave e imprimir por pantalla el texto “modificado”.

Tengo más o menos una idea de como guardar la palabra clave y el texto por líneas.

Este es el código que llevo:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX 4 //Este es el nº máximo de líneas

int main()
{
int i;

char clave[15];
char linea[20];
char *texto[MAX]; //array dinámico para el texto

printf("Introduce la palabra clave\n");
gets(clave);

for(i=0; i<MAX; i++)
    texto[i]=NULL; //Inicializo a NULL

printf("Texto original\n=============\n");

for(i=0; i<MAX; i++)
{
    printf("Introduce la %dº linea:\n",i);
    gets(linea);//leo las lineas del texto

    if(strstr(linea,clave)==NULL)
    {
        texto[i]=(char*) malloc(strlen(linea)+1);//guardo bloque 
        strcpy(texto[i],linea);//le adjudico las lineas al texto
    }
}
```

A partir de aquí estoy estancado, **¿cómo comparo la palabra clave y la identifico en las lineas de texto para eliminarla, e imprimir de nuevo el texto modificado en pantalla?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Necesitas saber qué líneas estas descartando y agregar al array `texto` tan solo las líneas que no contengan la palabra clave.

El primer cambio que he realizado en tu código es cosmético:

```
printf("Introduce la %dº linea:\n",i+1); // REV:
```

He modificado `i` por `i+1` para que no muestres en la salida el texto `0º`.

Para solucionar tu problema, he definido la variable `j`, la cual inicializo a `0` e incrementaré cada vez que agregue una línea al array `texto`.

```
int i, j = 0;
```

Más tarde, dentro del `if` que compara si la clave existe dentro de la línea introducida, asigno el buffer reservado a la linea de texto `j`

```
texto[j]=(char*) malloc(strlen(linea)+1);//guardo bloque
```

Copio la linea introducida en el `texto[j]` e incremento el valor de `j` una vez se realiza el copiado.

```
strcpy(texto[j++],linea);//le adjudico las lineas al texto
```

Al final del código, imprimo el array con las líneas agregadas:

```
printf( "Resultado: \n" );
for(i=0; i<j; i++ ) 
{ 
    printf( texto[i] );
    printf( "\n" );
}
```

**CONSIDERACIONES**

- Como se ha comentado, no se están liberando las cadenas reservadas
- La función `gets` es muy peligrosa, es fácil conseguir un Buffer Overflow, habría que cambiarlo por `fgets(str, 19, stdin);`.
- Hay otras consideraciones, como por ejemplo el bucle de incialización del array `texto`, el cual no es necesario.

Te pongo el código completo:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX 4 //Este es el nº máximo de líneas

int main()
{
    int i, j = 0;

    char clave[15];
    char linea[20];
    char *texto[MAX]; //array dinámico para el texto

    printf("Introduce la palabra clave\n");
    gets(clave);

    for(i=0; i<MAX; i++)
        texto[i]=NULL; //Inicializo a NULL

    printf("Texto original\n=============\n");

    for(i=0; i<MAX; i++)
    {
        printf("Introduce la %dº linea:\n",i+1); // REV:

        if(strstr(linea,clave)==NULL)
        {
            printf( "Copiando %s en la linea %d\n", linea, i );
            texto[j]=(char*) malloc(strlen(linea)+1);//guardo bloque 
            strcpy(texto[j++],linea);//le adjudico las lineas al texto
        }
    }

    printf( "Resultado: \n" );
    for(i=0; i<j; i++ ) 
    { 
        printf( texto[i] );
        printf( "\n" );
    }

}
```

Comment: En efecto, es la solución, gracias, luego no es necesario liberar memoria dinámica al final de la ejecución?

Comment: @AguaMineral Sería recomendable hacerlo. En SO modernos la memoria dinámica se libera automáticamente al finalizar el programa... pero no deja de ser una buena práctica acostumbrarse a liberar la memoria cuando ya no es necesaria. El no liberarla hace que la aplicación acapare recursos que no necesita, llegando al extremo de acaparar toda la memoria libre del sistema.

Answer (score 3):

Pues deberías comparar cada linea con la clave y con strstr comprobar si devuelve un valor o no, en caso de que no la linea no contendra la clave. Te pongo el ejemplo para una linea:

```
if(strstr(linea,clave) != NULL) {
printf( "La linea \"%s\" contiene la clave %s\n", linea,clave );
}
else
{
printf( "La linea \"%s\" no contiene la clave %s\n", linea,clave );
}
```

> La función char *strstr(const char *haystack,
>   const char *needle) busca la primera ocurrencia de la la subcadena needle en la cadena haystack y devuelve un puntero a tal ocurrencia y nulo si no encuentra ninguna coincidencia.

[Más info](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_strstr.htm)

Comment: Gracias por el aporte, justo fue lo que pensé, pero estaba equivocado al hacer:" ==NULL" y no " !=NULL".